# android kotlin: Insert variable to strings.xml entry

Tags: android, string, kotlin, text

I know that its possible to insert local variables into hardcoded strings, like

```
val amount = "10"
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = "There are $amount things."
```

would output `There are 10 things.`.
However, when I try to do the same thing in the strings.xml file, like

```
<resources>
<string name="some_string">There are $amount things.</string>
</resources>
```

```
val amount = "10"
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = getString(R.string.some_string)
```

the output is `There are $amount things.`.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```xml
<string name="some_string">There are %s things.</string>
```

and:

```kotlin
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).text = getString(R.string.some_string, amount)
```